# Android: onOptionsItemSelected() called in SherlockActivity, but not in SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: java, android

I have problems with the onOptionsItemSelected() in SherlockFragmentActivity.
The onCreateOptionsMenu() is called and the option menu is built perfectly, but when I click on an Options item, the onOptionsItemSelected() isn't called.

I tried the same following code in a test Project using SherlockActivity and there it works:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "hi").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "ha").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == 1) {
            // Do someting!

        }
        return true;
    }
```

In both cases, the following imports are done:

```
   import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
   import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
   import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

Does anyone know help? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using `SherlockFragmentActivity` in your minimal test project?  I have used `onOptionsItemSelected()` in activities that inherit from `SherlockFragmentActivity` on many occasions and never had trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried now and it works with SherlockFragmentActivity, but still only in the minimal test Project. Do you have an idea what could affect it in my large Project? Do the fragments play a role (they don't have any options menu)?

Comment: Sorry, don't know.  If I were working this problem, I would either slowly tear-down my broken Activity or slowly build-up my working Activity until I found the point where it breaks.  Then you can figure out how to solve.

Comment: Thank you! Now I copied the Project and rebuilt my SherlockFragmentActivity and found the problem. My class already contained public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item), and this will be called instead of onOptionsItemSelected. I need this because of the back button at the top left site of an actionbar.

Comment: Great! You should put this as an answer and accept it in case someone else has this problem, they can easily find it.

Comment: Also, you can capture the Home button in `onOptionsItemSelected()`, just check for `item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home`

Comment: Yes I will post it as an answer, but as I am new here, I can answer my own questions not before the question is ten hours old. Is there anything from onOptionsItemSelected and onMenuItemSelected better, or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: based on the API docs, it seems like `onMenuItemSelected` is really not for this purpose and that you should be using `onOptionsItemSelected` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this happens because you don't set [MenuItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setOnMenuItemClickListener%28android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener%29) (you create items in code).
But if you [define menu from xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml) Android will set listener and fire onOptionsItemSelected on click.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried definig it from XML now, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! Now I copied the Project and rebuilt my SherlockFragmentActivity and found the problem. My class already contained public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item), and this will be called instead of onOptionsItemSelected. I need this because of the back button at the top left site of an actionbar.